# Doing a Switch in Handler (ProgressDialog)

Tags: java, android

I have encountered a problem in my Android application.  I need to create a switch so I can put multiple messages in a handler instead of creating a million handlers.  Here is my code:

```
String text1 = spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString().trim();
String text2 = spinner2.getSelectedItem().toString().trim();

dialog1 = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), "", "Calculating...");

        if (text1.equals("US Dollar - USD") && text2.equals("Euro - EUR") && edittextdollars.length() > 0 && edittexteuros.length()==0) {
            Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try{
                    handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
                    convertvalues("USD", "EUR");
                    }
                    catch (Exception e) {

                    }

                }
            });
            thread.start();
        }

public Handler handler = new Handler () {
    public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
        dialog1.dismiss();
        convertvalues("USD", "EUR");
        }
    }
;
```

This works, but I want to create more messages for multiple if statements, like this:

```
if (text1.equals("US Dollar - USD") && text2.equals("Euro - EUR") && edittextdollars.length() > 0 && edittexteuros.length()==0) {
            Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try{
                    handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
                    convertvalues("USD", "EUR");
                    }
                    catch (Exception e) {

                    }

                }
            });
            thread.start();
        }
if (text1.equals("US Dollar - USD") && text2.equals("Euro - EUR") && edittexteuros.length() > 0 && edittextdollars.length()==0) {
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try{
                    handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
                    convertvalues2("EUR","USD");
                    }
                    catch (Exception e) {

                    }

                }
            });
            thread.start();
        }
        if (text1.equals("Euro - EUR") && text2.equals("US Dollar - USD") && edittextdollars.length() > 0 && edittexteuros.length()==0) {
Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try{
                    handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
                    convertvalues("EUR","USD");
                    }
                    catch (Exception e) {

                    }

                }
            });
            thread.start();
        }
```

How do I achieve this?  Is it with a switch, or something else.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

P.S. 
Since I am a beginner, it would be great if you post code also with your answer.  That would be great.  And once again, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Switch statements in java work with ints and enums and a few [other types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html).

So in your case, you might want to setup an enum to hold the possible values that you might want to switch on.

```
    public enum Currency{
    USD, 
    EUR
}

private void test(Currency currency){
    switch (currency){
    case USD:
        doUsdStuff();
        break;
    case EUR:
        doEurStuff();
        break;
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could declare int values instead of enums.

Since you have two values, you might do two switch statements, saving the value of each then do one call to convertValues() with the saved values.

Comment: But how do I call this in my if/then statement?

Comment: The purpose of the switch is to get rid of the multiple if/else statements.

Answer (score 0):

You would use variables instead. Try to extract the things that change, and build the code around that. In your case the call to `convertvalues2` varies, so extract the arguments to variables and use those.

```
final String fromCurrency = text1.substring(text1.length() - 3);
final String toCurrency = text2.substring(text2.length() - 3);
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try{
            handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
            convertvalues2(fromCurrency, toCurrency);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
        }
     }
});
```